# Change TextView text when EditText text matches string. No Buttons

Tags: android, mobile, android-edittext, textview

I have a string variable used in a method, and I would like to compare the text from my EditText to that variable.

As soon as they match, I would like to update the TextView to something different than what it currently is. Code below:

```
public void textChangeMethod() {

TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_Text);
EditText myEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_Edit);

String testString = "Test";
String matchString = myEdit.getText().toString();

if(matchString == testString){
   myText.setText("Finished")
}
```

However, the problem is, this if statement runs before the user is done with typing the ful word in, and it'll never be true. I would rater not use a button to fire this off.

I have tried implementing a TextWatcher, but nothing happens. I am new to android development and am not sure I fully understand how to use it.

I also thought about using a countdown timer, and then a while loop to constantly check the edit text value against the string. I want to be as efficient as possible.

**FULL CODE BELOW**

```
public class NewClass extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewAPI")



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);

    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    textChangeMethod();


}





public void textChangeMethod() {



    //Local variables
    final TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_Text);
    final String testString = "Test";
    EditText myEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_Edit);
    final String matchString = myEdit.getText().toString();




    TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() { 

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int i, int i2,int i3)   
        {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s) && matchString.equals(s)){
          myText.setText("Finished");
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
        {   
        }
    };

    myEdit.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

}
```

**FINAL EDIT**

Both answers helped. I was also able to look more online and get an in depth article on Text Watcher.

I needed to use 'aterTextChange'. However, now I have a new problem. If I cannot figure it out, I will be back to post a new question.

As always, thanks for the support.

***FINAL EDIT #2***

So the problem I was having after implementing afterTextChanged was that my app crashed and kept flashing, and was completely unusable.

After a quick stack search, it appears I need to implement removeTextChangedListener in order for it to stop being called.

All is well. I wish I could accept both answers. Thank you.

Comment: you get your EditText String when your Activity initiated , so it's empty and the condition on onTextChange() never been true! so you should get it on onTextChange() befor if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textwatcher is your solution , if you have problem to implement it plz post your codes, but here is a sample code to implement Textwatcher and you can put your if statement in onTextChange() callback function :

```
TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() { 
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
        {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before,int count)   
        {
          if(s.equals(testString)){
          myText.setText("Finished")
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
        {   
        }
    };

    EditText filterText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtItemFilter);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

and also don't use == operator to compare Strings instead use :

> if(matchString.equals(testString))

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your help, however my text still isn't changing.

I read through the TextWatcher doc on the Android site, and the onTextChanged states that within `s`, the `count` characters beginning at `start` have just replaced old text that had length `before`.

I don't know what this means. Do I straight copy/pasted your code into my method, and still the TextView text does not change. Do I need to do something with the `int` variables within the arguments for onTexChanged?

Comment: has it been called when you enter characters to your EditText?put breakpoints to check wether it's been called or not,and it should work without working with count variable.

Comment: Added Full Code. Im not sure I know what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

TextWatcher should work just fine you only need to initialize the listener once, so in your ***onCrateView()*** in an Activity. Also like @Arash said use ***.equals(CharSequence c)*** instead of the **==** operand. Other than that hopefully your question is answered.

```
final TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_Text);
EditText myEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_Edit);

myEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence) && myText.equals(charSequence)) {
            // Do something with myText
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { }
});
```

**EDIT**

After seeing your full code this line:

```
final String matchString = myEdit.getText().toString();
```

This String will be empty therefore it will never evaluate the statement. Its blank because the user has never input anything. Say you wanted to match the string "Hello" you would do this:

```
public void textChangeMethod() {
    final TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_Text);
    EditText myEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_Edit);
    final String matchString = "Hello";

    TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() { 

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int i, int i2,int i3)   
        {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s) && matchString.equals(s)){
               myText.setText("Finished");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
    };

    myEdit.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}
```